# AngularJS function in JavaScript-generated html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I am a newbie at AngularJS. I'm trying to set attributes properly to JavaScript generated html code but every attempt so far has failed.

My code (excluding my failed attempts): https://codepen.io/walkerdude5/pen/JxjgqP?editors=1010

```
angular
  .module("MyApp", ["ngMaterial", "ngMessages", "material.svgAssetsCache"])
  .controller("AppCtrl", function($compile, $scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.showPrompt = function(ev) {
      var confirm = $mdDialog
        .prompt()
        .title("Note Editor")
        .placeholder("New Note")
        .targetEvent(ev)
        .ok("Save")
        .cancel("Discard");
      $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function(result) {
        $scope.variable = "update note function";
      });
    };
  });

table = document.getElementById("example2");
tr = table.insertRow(0);
tr.insertCell(0);
tr.insertCell(1);
tr = table.insertRow(0);
tr.insertCell(0);
tr.insertCell(1);
table.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML = "dummyContent1";
table.rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML = "dummyContent2";
table.rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML = "dummyContent3";

var angularTD = table.rows[1].cells[1];
//prompt dialog functionality in this cell
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <tbody id="example2">
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- what I want to be able to do -->
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-app="MyApp">
  <button ng-click="showPrompt($event)">
      Prompt Dialog
    </button>
</div>
```

Edit: I pasted one my attempts, basically what I am trying to do is create a button with ng-click attribute, append the butotn to a div with ng-controller and app attributes, and append the div to a TD created and accessed through JavaScript. The TD must be created through javascript because the number of TD created is dependent on web socket data.

`var angdiv= document.createElement("DIV");
                                        angdiv.setAttribute("ng-controller","AppCtrl");
                                        angdiv.setAttribute("app","MyApp");
                                        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                                        btn.setAttribute("ng-click","showPrompt($event)");
                                        btn.innerHTML='View';
                                        angdiv.appendChild(btn);
                                        td.appendChild(angdiv);`

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Please revise to better describe what you're trying to accomplish and in what way it's not working.

Comment: what are the attributes you are trying to set?

Comment: By the way, one of the core tenets of AngularJS is to not directly modify the DOM. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/1264804. Your table should have an ngRepeat directive on it and you should only be modifying the data object that it consumes.

Comment: updated question with more info